# How to set a large stty size?(default 80x24)

Tags: kernel, console, serial-console, framebuffer, kms

I'm really not sure where is the problem, so I'm putting all message i think helpful here.

```
dmesg | grep drm
[    0.316388] fb0: switching to cirrusdrmfb from EFI VGA
[    0.316769] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC0000000
[    0.316769] [drm] vram aper at 0xC0000000
[    0.316769] [drm] size 33554432
[    0.316770] [drm] fb depth is 16
[    0.316770] [drm]    pitch is 2048
[    0.316791] fbcon: cirrusdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    0.322191] cirrus 0000:00:02.0: fb0: cirrusdrmfb frame buffer device
[    0.322195] [drm] Initialized cirrus 1.0.0 20110418 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    0.322279] [drm] Initialized vgem 1.0.0 20120112 for vgem on minor 1
[    0.322293] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    0.322294] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    0.322340] [drm] Initialized vkms 1.0.0 20180514 for vkms on minor 2

dmesg | grep modeset
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.2.1-lfs-20190714-systemd root=/dev/sda2 ro ro root=/dev/sda2 console=tty0 console=ttyS0 loglevel=6 modeset
[    0.140663] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.2.1-lfs-20190714-systemd root=/dev/sda2 ro ro root=/dev/sda2 console=tty0 console=ttyS0 loglevel=6 modeset

stty size
24 80

kernel parameters
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ro root=/dev/sda2 console=tty0 console=ttyS0 loglevel=6 modeset"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1600x900
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

tty
/dev/ttyS0

# Console display driver support
#
CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK=y
CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK_SIZE=64
# CONFIG_VGACON_SOFT_SCROLLBACK_PERSISTENT_ENABLE_BY_DEFAULT is not set
CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE_COLUMNS=132
CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE_ROWS=60
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DETECT_PRIMARY=y
# CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_ROTATION is not set
# CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE_DEFERRED_TAKEOVER is not set
```

I use qemu via ssh, so i want the tty show more columns and rows to fit my ssh client.
I use -vga cirrus and already config virtual gpu driver for this, dependency module also config which is shown in dmesg above.
If you think more information is needed, please comment.
Hope you can help me out >_<

Comment: `stty rows 30 cols 100` should do it, no? Am I missing something?

Comment: @NickD, Thanks! It seems work, but i realized that if the stty rows it's more than my ssh client rows, then the screen output will completely mess.Do you know the reason? My host machine show tty is /dev/pts/1, it seems can auto resize the tty size, how can it do this?

Comment: Also, I want to make this size persistent, so where is the config file of stty? Thanks again :-)